# Drhystone benchmark on 32 bit micrcontroller

Tags: caching, benchmarking, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

Currently I am doing a performance comparison on two 32bit microcontrollers. I used Dhrystone benchmark to run on both microcontrollers. One microcontroller has 4KB I-cache  while second coontroller has 8KB of I-cache. Both microcontrollers are using same tool chain. As much as possible I kept same static and run-time settings onboth microcontrollers. But microcontroller with 4KB cache are faster than 8KB cache microcontroller. Both microcontroller are from same vendor and based on same CPU.

Could anyone provide some information why microcontroller with 4KB cache is faster than other?

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarks are in general useless.  dhrystone being one of the oldest ones and it may have had a little bit of value back then, before pipelines and too much compiler optimization.  I think I gave up on dhrystone 15 years ago roughly about the time I started using it.

It is trivial to demonstrate that this code

```
.globl ASMDELAY
ASMDELAY:
    sub r0,r0,#1
    bne ASMDELAY
    bx lr
```

Which is primarily two INSTRUCTIONS, can vary WIDELY in execution time on the same chip if you understand how modern processors work.  The simple trick to seeing this is turn off the caches and prefetchers and such, and place this code at offset 0x0000, call it with some value.  place it at 0x0004 repeat, then at 0x0008, repeat.  keep doing this.  You can put one, two, etc nops between the subtract and branch.  try it at various offsets.

THEN, turn on and of caches for each of these alignments, if you have a prefetch outside the processor for the flash, turn that on and off.

THEN, vary your clocks, esp for those MCUs where you have to adjust the wait states based on clock rate.

On a SINGLE MCU, you are going to see those essentially two instructions vary in execution time by a very large amount.  Lets just say 20 times longer in some cases than others.

Now take a small program or a small fraction of the dhrystone program.  Compile that for your mcu, how many instructions do you see?  Make minor to major optimization and other variations on the compile command line, how much does the code change.  If two instructions can vary by lets call it 20 times in execution time, how bad can it get for 200 instructions or 2000 instructions?  It can get pretty bad.

If you take the dhrystone programs you have right now with the compiler options you have right now, go into your bootstrap, add one nop (causing the entire binary to shift by one instruction in flash) run again.  Add two, three, four.  You are still not comparing different mcus just running your benchmark on one system.

Run with and without d cache, with and without i cache if you have each of those.  turn on and off the flash prefetch if you have one and if you have a write buffer you can turn on and of try that.  Still remaining on the same compiler same options same mcu.

Take the different functions in the dhrystone source code, and re-arrange them in the source code.  instead of Proc_1, Proc_2, Proc_3 make it Proc_1, Proc_3, Proc_2.  Do all of the above again. Re-arrange again, repeat.

Before leaving this mcu you should now see that the execution time of the same source code which is completely unmodified (other than perhaps re-arranging functions) can and will have vastly different execution times.

if you then start changing compiler options or keep the same source and change compilers, you will see even more of a difference in execution time.

How is it possible that dhrystone benchmarks today or from way back had a single result for each platform?  Simple, that result was just one of a wide range, not really representing the platform.

So then if you try to compare two different hardware platforms be it the same arm core inside a different mcu from the same vendor or different vendors.  the arm core, assuming (which is not a safe assumption) it is the same source with the same compile/build options, even assuming the same verilog compile and synthesis was used. you can have that same core change based on arm provided options.  Anyway, how the vendor be it the same vendor in two instances or two different vendors wraps that same core, you will see variations.  Then take a completely different core be it another arm or a mips, etc.  How could you gain any value comparing those using a program like this that itself varies widely on each platform?

You cant.  What you can do is use benchmarks to give the illusion of one thing being better than another, one computer is faster than another, one compiler is faster than another.  In order to sell computers or compilers.  Sprints coverage is within one percent of Verizons...does that tell us anything useful?  Nope.

If you were to eliminate the compiler from the equation, and if these are truly the same "CPU", same rev of source from ARM, built the same way, then they should fetch the same, but the size of the cache is part of that so it may already be a different cpu implementation as the width or depth of the cache can affect things.  In software it is like needing a 32 bit pointer rather than a 16 bit pointer (17 bit instead of 16, but you cant have a 17 bit generally in logic you can).

Anyway, if you compile the code under test one time for an address space that is common to both platforms, use that same binary exactly for that space, can attach different bootstrap code as needed, note the C library calls strcpy, etc also have to be the same in the same space between platforms to eliminate the compiler and alignment from messing you up.  this may or may not level the playing field.

If you want to believe these are the same cpu, then turn the caches off, eliminate the compiler variations by doing the above.  See if they execute the same.  Copy the program to ram and run in ram, eliminate the flash issues.  I assume you have them both clocked the same with the same wait states in the flash?

if they are the same cpu and the chip vendor has with these two chips made the memory system take the same number of clocks say for ram accesses, and it is really the same cpu, you should be able to get the same time by eliminating optimizations (caching, flash prefetching, alignment).

what you are probably seeing is some form of alignment with how the code lies in memory from the compiler vs cache lines, or it could be much much simpler it could be just the differences in the caches, how the hits and misses work and the 4KB is just more lucky than the 8KB for this particular program compiled a certain way, aligned in memory a certain way, etc.

With the simple two instruction loop above it is easy to see some of the reasons why performance varies on the same system, if your modern cpu fetches 8 instructions at a time and your loop gets too close to the tail end of that fetch, the prefetch may think it needs to fetch another 8 beyond that costing you those clock cycles.  Certainly as you exactly straddle two "fetch lines" as I call them with those two instructions it is going to cost you a lot more cycles per loop even with a cache.  Same problem happens when those two instructions approach a cache line (as you vary their alignment per test) eventually it takes two cache line reads instead of one to fetch those two instructions.  At least the first time through there is an extra cache line read.  The extra clocks for that first time through is something you can see using a simple benchmark like that while playing with alignment.

Michael Abrash, Zen of Assembly Language.  There is an epub/etc you can build from github of this book.  the 8088 was obsolete when this book came out if that is all you see 8088 stuff, then you are completely missing the point.  It applies to the most modern processors today, how to view the problem, how to test, how to time the test, how to interpret the results.  All the stuff I have mentioned so far, and all the things I know about this that I have not mentioned, all came from that books knowledge applied for however many decades I have been doing this.

So again if you have truly eliminated the compiler, alignment, the cpu, the memory system tied to that cpu, etc and it is down to only the size of the cache varies.  Then it is probably related to how the cache line fetches hit and miss differently based on alignment of the code relative to the cache lines for the two caches.  One is hitting more and missing less and/or evicting better for this particular binary.  You can try rearranging the functions, can add nops, or if you cant get at the bootstrap then add whole functions or more code (another printf, etc) at a lower address in the binary causing the linker to slide the code under test through to different addresses changing how the program lines up with the cache lines.  Since the functions in the code under test are so big (more than a few instructions to implement) you would have to start modifying the program in order to get a finer grained adjustment of binary relative to cache lines.

You most definitely should see execution time differences on the two platforms if you adjust alignment and or wholesale re-arrange the binary based on functions being re-arranged.

Bottom line benchmarks dont really tell you much, the results have more of a negative stink to them than a positive joy.  Without a re-write a particular benchmark or application may just do better on one platform (be it everything is the same but the size of the cache or two completely different architectures) even when you try to vary the results due to alignment, turning on and off prefetching, write buffering, branch prediction, etc.  Pulling out all the tricks you can come up with one may vary from x to y the other from n to m and maybe there is some overlap in the ranges.  For these two platforms that you say are similiar except for cache size I would hope you could find a combination where sometimes A is faster than B and at least one combination where B is faster than A, with the same features turned on and off for both in that comparision.  If/when you switch to some other application/benchmark this all starts over again, no reason to assume dhrystone results predict any other code under test.  The only program that matters, esp on an MCU is the final build of your application.  Just remember changing a single line of code, or even adding a single nop in the bootstrap can have dramatic results in performance sometimes several TIMES slower or faster from a single nop.